# PRINT VALUE OF OBJECT || PLSQL

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, cursor, sys-refcursor

I want to see values of object as output.

**My PL/SQL Code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XPROC( p_val       IN     xxx%TYPE DEFAULT NULL,
      p_debt_receivable_out      OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
invoice_det get_debt_type;

BEGIN

insert into tmp_invoice_det  xxxxxxxxx;

select get_debt_obj(INVOICE_NUMBER,
INVOICE_DATE,
INVOICE_PERIOD,
DUE_AMOUNT,
DUE_DATE,
INVOICE_STATUS,
INVOICE_ADDRESS) bulk collect into
invoice_det from  tmp_invoice_det;

OPEN p_debt_receivable_out FOR
select total_debt,TOTAL_RECEIVABLE,invoice_det as invoice_detail from xxxxxxxxx;
  
END;
```

**How I call:**

```
set serveroutput on
variable  result refcursor
DECLARE
p_val VARCHAR2(144);
 
BEGIN
  p_val:= ‘12345’;

XPROC(p_val, :result);

END;
/

print result;
```

**OUTPUT:**

| TOTAL_DEBT | TOTAL_RECEIVABLE | INVOICE_DETAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 159 | 0 | GET_DEBT_TYPE([CDR_INQUIRY.GET_DEBT_OBJ],[CDR_INQUIRY.GET_DEBT_OBJ],[CDR_INQUIRY.GET_DEBT_OBJ]) |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

| TOTAL_DEBT | TOTAL_RECEIVABLE | INVOICE_DETAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 159 | 0 | INVOICE_DETAIL: value , INVOICE_DATE: value ,INVOICE_PERIOD: value, ...... |

Comment: Your procedure doesn't display that output now; whatever calls the procedure does, and you haven't shown that. Some clients have built-in ability, such as via SQL Developer's `variable` and `print` commands, but they are client-specific. So, you need to edit your question to show how you are calling the procedure and how you are handing the ref cursor and getting the current output.

Comment: Question is updated.